# Why a dental visit before age 1?

Tags: dentistry, pediatrics, infant

I followed the recommendations to take my teething 10-month old to a dentist:

- [American Dental Association](https://www.mouthhealthy.org/en/babies-and-kids/first-dental-visit): the reasons given are to “check for mouth injuries, cavities or other issues”
- [American Association of Pediatric Dentistry](https://www.aapd.org/resources/parent/faq/): the reason given is “to prevent dental problems”.

In an hour-long visit, about 5 seconds involved the dentist actually looking at the few teeth that were visible (the remainder was mostly tapping health insurance and medical history into a tablet with a baby in one hand). No photos or X-rays. What was the point of this? How does a dentist identify “mouth injuries”, “cavities”, “other issues”, and “dental problems” with such a limited observation of a limited number of teeth? Can a cavity really form within a month of eruption? Are there conditions that don’t have obvious symptoms for which this visit is intended?

Comment: The links provide immediate reasons as far as I can see. What is it you don't quite follow?

Comment: @ChrisRogers I added quotes of the reasons I found; they seem overly general and illogical.

Comment: Sounds like your 10-month old didn't have any problems. The visit may have been a bit different if they did.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did the other 59 minutes and 55 seconds of the visit consist of?

Comment: @CareyGregory edited to add parenthetical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The American Academy of Pediatrics [Bright Futures](https://brightfutures.aap.org/Pages/default.aspx) public health initiative has developed a comprehensive assessment of approaches to [Promoting Oral Health](https://brightfutures.aap.org/Bright%20Futures%20Documents/BF4_OralHealth.pdf) in infants and children.

The ["Promoting Oral Health"](https://brightfutures.aap.org/Bright%20Futures%20Documents/BF4_OralHealth.pdf) document describes in detail the reasoning and evidence for the recommendations.

Of particular note is the section on 1-4 years:

> The key oral health priorities of this developmental
> stage are ...
> preventing caries and developing healthy oral
> hygiene habits. Early childhood also is a good
> time for **parents, caregivers, and health care professionals to build positive dietary habits** as they
> introduce new foods and the child establishes taste
> preferences [emphasis added].

Thus, while a comprehensive dental exam and imaging studies may not be completed, the visit provides the opportunity to establish care with a Pediatric Dentist, review these positive habits, and answer any questions you may have.

Dental caries are a major [public health problem](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/sugars-and-dental-caries) which disproportionally effect children with [disadvantaged socioeconomic status](https://www.cdc.gov/oralhealth/oral_health_disparities/index.htm). These recommendations are one of many ways public health advocates are attempting to decrease these disparities.